# How would I alter this javascript to close the current container when a new container is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can come up with a really long way around (toggle a opens a and closes b and c, toggle b opens b and closes a and c) but I'm wondering if there is a smarter/quicker option.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbZDv/1/

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();

$("p.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
});
```

The page: http://orionhistoricalsociety.org/videos/

Comment: Just close all toogles before open toogle you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove active class from existing trigger classes, then toggle class as you have been:

```
$("p.trigger").click(function(){
    //removed active class from all p.trigger elements
    $("p.trigger").removeClass("active");
    //hide shown toggle_containers
    $(".toggle_container").hide();
    //show requested toggle_container
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

How about using radio buttons?

Here's my idea: CSS can hide the buttons and use a label to provide a way to select them, then the CSS can only show content for "checked" radio buttons.

Example below:

```css
.option_container { margin: 10px 0px; }
.option_container > .block { background:#f0f0f0; }

/* Option styles */
.option_container > label { cursor: pointer; }
.option_container > input[type="radio"] { display: none; }
.option_container > input[type="radio"] ~ .block { display: none; }
.option_container > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .block { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="option_container">
    <input id="option1" type="radio" name="option" value="option1" />
    <label for="option1">Click here to expand and reveal more information</label>
    <div class="block">Content goes here.</div>
</div>

<div class="option_container">
    <input id="option2" type="radio" name="option" value="option2" />
    <label for="option2">Click here to expand and reveal more information</label>
    <div class="block">Content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

Note: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Achecked), ":checked" is not supported by IE < 9